# Apache.Ignite.NET Query Key/Value data via ODBC

Tags: .net, ignite

Ignite has (amongst others) the use cases "in-memory key/value store" and "SQL via ODBC". I wonder if these use cases can be combined.

Let's use this model:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Add a 'Person' to the key/value store:

```
using (var ignite = Ignition.Start())
{
    var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, Person>("person-cache");
    cache.Put(1, new Person { Name = "Test", Age=7 });
}
```

Now, can I do something like

```
SELECT * FROM Person;
```

via an ODBC connection? If yes, code samples preferably in C# / Ignite.NET are very much appreciated.
Or is it not possible because are we talking about entirely separate data-stores / caches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can do it with [Apache Ignite](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/).
There are three things to do:

1. update your Person model with the desired SQL fields:

   ```
   class Person
   {
       [QuerySqlField(IsIndexed = true)]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       [QuerySqlField]
       public int Age { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Add SQL query types (Person type) to CacheConfiguration
3. Don't forget to use a schema name (= Cache name) with quotation marks when accessing a table:

   ```
       using (var ignite = Ignition.Start())
       {
           var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, Person>(new CacheConfiguration("person-cache", typeof(Person)));

           cache.Put(1, new Person { Name = "Test", Age = 7 });

           var dbConnection = new OdbcConnection(@"DRIVER={Apache Ignite};ADDRESS=localhost:10800");
           try
           {
               dbConnection.Open();

               using (var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
               {
                   dbCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM ""person-cache"".Person WHERE Name=?";
                   dbCommand.Parameters.Add("Name", OdbcType.Char).Value = "Test";
                   var dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                   var fCount = dbReader.FieldCount;
                   while (dbReader.Read())
                   {
                       for (var i = 0; i < fCount; i++)
                       {
                           var val = dbReader.GetString(i);
                           var name = dbReader.GetName(i);

                           Console.WriteLine(name + "=" + val);
                       }
                   }
                   dbReader.Close();
               }
           }
           catch (OdbcException ex)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(ex);
           }

           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   ```

Thank you,
Alexey

Comment: For other newbies like myself. Do not forget to install the appropriate ODBC driver that you find here: apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\platforms\cpp\bin\odbc\ignite-odbc-amd64.msi / ignite-odbc-x86.msi

Comment: Your code sample works great. Are you aware of a SQL editor / GUI that supports Apache.Ignite? I tried https://www.etl-tools.com/database-browser/overview.html and Excel - external ODBC data source without success.

Comment: I used DBeaver (GUI) some time ago. Please see https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.1/docs/sql-tooling for more details. Apache Ignite 2.3 has SQLLine (without GUI, just a console app) that could be run from apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin/bin/sqlline.bat or .sh